# Download files from Artifactory to Teamcity without retaining their full path

Tags: teamcity, artifactory

I am using

- TeamCity Enterprise 2017.1.2 (build 46812)
- Artifactory Professional 5.3.1 rev 50046
- Teamcity has the Artifactory plug-in installed (ver 2.3.0)

**The task is simple** - download files from Artifactory to Teamcity build:

- From Artifactory `MyRepo/RootFolder/ProjectFolder/1.2.3/<files>`
- To TC `%checkoutdir%/artifacts/<files>`

The `<files>` part of the path contains both folders and files and I want to retain their structure.

The download spec json is:

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "MyRepo/RootFolder/ProjectFolder/1.2.3/",
      "target": "artifacts/"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

However, the files get downloaded into a different location than I would expect:

- Actual: `artifacts/RootFolder/ProjectFolder/1.2.3/<files>`
- Expected: `artifacts/<files>`

The whole path from Artifactory gets appended after the target directory. How do I tell the plugin to only use the relative path of files *after* the specified root? I have tried fiddling about with wildcards, slashes etc, but nothing helped.

I had to create an extra build step where I manually move files to the structure I expect, but I would prefer not to have to do that.

---

**WORKING ANSWER:**

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "MyRepo/RootFolder/ProjectFolder/1.2.3/(*)",
      "target": "artifacts/{1}",
      "flat": "true"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize your target structure by using Placeholders in your File Specs as described [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+File+Specs#UsingFileSpecs-UsingPlaceholders).
Placeholders allow you to capture a specific section of your File Spec "pattern" property value, and use it inside the "target" property value.

In your case, the download File Spec should look like this:

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "MyRepo/RootFolder/ProjectFolder/1.2.3/(*)",
      "target": "artifacts/{1}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I tried this before, but it does not work as expected - let's say I have a folder in <files> called `util`. Your File Spec creates this structure on download: `artifacts/util/RootFolder/ProjectFolder/1.2.3/util/<files-in-util>` - it simply places the whole directory tree into a folder matched by (*). Not to mention this does not do anything different with files.

Comment: I see. So if I understand you correctly, you'd like a flat layout of the files under the artifacts directory. I think that adding the "flat": "true" property to your original File Spec should do the trick for you.

Comment: Thank you for nudging me in the right direction. I have tried `flat` before, but without the `(*),{1}` placeholders. Using both together yields the results I want.