# How to download only files (without the folder) from Artifactory

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I have the below structure in `Artifactory`:

[image: artifact]

Now I want to download the file using `jenkinsfile` to my `WORKSPACE`, but only the file itself (without the folder `v1.0.2`). What I should modify here in order to make it works?

```
    def downloadSpec = """{
        "files": [
            {
                "pattern": "generic-17067-local/v1.0.2/*.dacpac", 
                "target": ""
            }
        ]
    }"""

    server.download(downloadSpec)
```

Comment: Answer was found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45164794/download-files-from-artifactory-to-teamcity-without-retaining-their-full-path

Comment: Yes, its the same thread I've put in my comment. This is the answer